# Shell Script for Java not working

Tags: java, bash, shell, makefile

I am using a make file to create a simple shell script to execute a Java program, the makefile follows:

```
top:
    javac -d classfiles -sourcepath src src/kruskal.java
test:
    echo java -classpath classfiles kruskal \$\* > kruskal
    chmod +x kruskal
clean:
    rm -f classfiles/"/".class
```

However, when I run make test then try to execute my program (which takes in command line arguments) java tries to run the program using the arguments "-classpath" and "classfiles" as arguments, causing the program to throw a FileNotFoundException. I'm running the program with:

```
kruskal g1.txt
```

Am I doing something wrong? This is my first time working with shell scripts, any help is appreciated.

Edit: here is the exact error as well:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: classfiles (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at kruskal.readInputs(kruskal.java:20)
    at kruskal.main(kruskal.java:172)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at kruskal.BFS(kruskal.java:132)
    at kruskal.main(kruskal.java:177)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To escape `$` in Makefile use another `$`. The current content of `kruskal` file is actually `java -classpath classpath kruskal *` and `*` is expanded with the files in current directory which is `classpath` among others. Or maybe even worse the `*` is expanded already by shell running the `echo` command.

So to make the `Makefile` line correct:

```
test:
         echo "java -classpath classfiles kruskal \$$*" > kruskal
```

Comment: Thank you! Turns out it was indeed expanding the files in the current directory and using them as the arguments.